# angular2-mdl: Break layout in components does not work

Tags: angular, angular2-mdl

For a given layout from the demo-app http://mseemann.io/angular2-mdl/layout

```
<div class="demo-container" mdl-shadow="2">
<mdl-layout mdl-layout-fixed-header mdl-layout-header-seamed>
  <mdl-layout-header>
     <mdl-layout-header-row>
        <mdl-layout-title>Title</mdl-layout-title>
        <mdl-layout-spacer></mdl-layout-spacer>
        <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
        <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
           <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href>Link</a>
           <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href>Link</a>
           <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href>Link</a>
        </nav>
     </mdl-layout-header-row>
  </mdl-layout-header>
  <mdl-layout-drawer>
     <mdl-layout-title>Title</mdl-layout-title>
     <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href>Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href>Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href>Link</a>
     </nav>
  </mdl-layout-drawer>
  <mdl-layout-content>
     <router-outlet ></router-outlet>
  </mdl-layout-content>
```

it works if I copy paste directly in app.html but if I break it up in reusable components. Let's say:

```
<div class="demo-container" mdl-shadow="2">
<mdl-layout mdl-layout-fixed-header mdl-layout-header-seamed>
  <header-comp></header-comp>
  <drawer-comp></drawer-comp>
<mdl-layout-content>
     <router-outlet ></router-outlet>
</mdl-layout-content>
```

Where `<header-comp></header-comp>` and `<drawer-comp></drawer-comp>` encapsulate part of the layout markup (`<mdl-layout-header>...</mdl-layout-header>` and `<mdl-layout-drawer>...</mdl-layout-drawer>` respectively)

**Both components does not render anything in place**

I am running Angular2 "2.0.0" (the brand new official final release) and angular-mdl "1.7.1" with Webpack as module bundler. It is good to say that all angular2-mdl directives rendered inside router-outlet are rendered properly. This leads to think that angular2-mdl is properly imported and installed.

More specifically, in `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [  
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        homeRouting,
        MdlModule
    ],
```

and both in `header.ts`and `drawer.ts`:

```
    providers: [
        MdlLayoutComponent
    ]
```

By last if I move one of my reusable component (let's say: `<header-comp></header-comp>`) out of the mark up (see below). The template content is rendered properly although the layout looks broken (as expected)

```
<header-comp></header-comp>    
<div class="demo-container" mdl-shadow="2">
     <mdl-layout mdl-layout-fixed-header mdl-layout-header-seamed>
     <drawer-comp></drawer-comp>
     <mdl-layout-content>
         <router-outlet ></router-outlet>
</mdl-layout-content>
```

I can workaround it using plain mdl or duplicating code but... what is happening?

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

The components `mdl-layout-header`, `mdl-layout-drawer` and `mdl-layout-content` are used as `@ContentChild` in `mdl-layout`. If they are not direct childs of `mdl-layout` angular will not find them. In fact they are `undefined` and you'll see nothing. (the reason is that the mdl html structure is different and they needs to be restructured).

If I understand right what you are trying to do: please remove the `mdl-layout-header` component from your `header-comp` and keep the `mdl-layout-header` component as a direct child of `mdl-layout` - in this way:

```
<mdl-layout mdl-layout-fixed-header mdl-layout-header-seamed>
   <mdl-layout-header>
      <header-comp></header-comp>
   </mdl-layout-header
   <mdl-layout-content>
     <router-outlet ></router-outlet>
   </mdl-layout-content>
</mdl-layout>
```

For the `mdl-layout-drawer` and `mdl-layout-content` you need to do the same.

Comment: Ok!, it works like a charm. Now I understand some unexpected behaviour I had when applying MDL markup to submodules as well. Thanks a lot!! you are doing a great work with angular-mdl! ... and just for understand it: who should restructure the 'wrong' mdl html you meant?, you or the mdl team?

Comment: no, no. the restructering is done by angular2-mdl :) I need to document this a little bit more...

Comment: @michael - I have mdl-layout-drawer and mdl-layout-header in the same component as they have common functionality. As you're saying in this answer that mdl-layout-drawer and mdl-layout-header must be direct children of mdl-layout, does that mean that it is not possible to put them in the same component? Is there a workaround or would I need to go back to regular mdl if I want to structure my code like this?

Comment: Hi, i have a question regarding this. Like @michael said "mdl-layout-header, mdl-layout-drawer and mdl-layout-content are used as ContentChild in mdl-layout". How should i pass the Events using EventEmitter from child <drawer-comp></drawer-comp> to <mdl-layout> as in this case <drawer-comp> will behave like grand child. I'm trying to send event from drawer to the component holding mdl-layout but its not working.