# Break layout in components does not work, solution

Tags: angular, material-design-lite

View solution: [angular2-mdl: Break layout in components does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550175/angular2-mdl-break-layout-in-components-does-not-work)

Comment: what is  your problem ? where is your code ?

Comment: I am giving the solution to work with MDL

Comment: so you should post it as answer/comment there, why are you posting this as question ?